# PHP MYSQL Select data from the last 24 hours and previous 24 hours

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a script that stores data in a MYSQL database every hour and I am working on putting that data into a graph. I would like to make a graph with two lines. The first line would be data from the last 24 hours and the second line would be the data from the previous 24 hours.

I have tried to query the database like this:

```
// this is for the first line in the graph
"SELECT * FROM database WHERE date >=(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR))";

// this is for the second line in the graph
"SELECT * FROM database WHERE date >=(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 48 HOUR)) AND date <=(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR))";
```

But the results aren't exactly correct.. I apologize if my MYSQL is nasty, I'm just learning it right now.

Interestingly the above code did not provide me with all the data from the first 24 hours or the previous 24 hours, but when I change the query like so:

```
// this is for the first line in the graph
"SELECT * FROM database WHERE date >=(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 48 HOUR))";

// this is for the second line in the graph
"SELECT * FROM database WHERE date >=(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)) AND date <=(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 2 DAY))";
```

It appears to work for some strange reason?

This is the format of my database:

```
id | data | date | time
0  | 0.00 |Y-d-m |H:i:s
```

Right now it has about 68 entries.

Can someone help me to understand this? Or recommend a better method? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data (preferredly in the form of `INSERT INTO ... VALUES(...` statements) and the results you get + the current value of Now() when you've ran the test script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the timezones of your php and mysql server are synchronized.